# Rewriting $(\log_{11}5)/(\log_{11} 15)$

Tags: logarithms

I'm struggling with this can anyone tell me the solution of this?

$$
\frac{\log_{11}{5}}{\log_{11}{15}}
$$

A) $\log_{11}{15}$

B) $\log_{11}{5}$

C) $\log_{5}{15}$

D) $\log_{15}{5}$

Comment: $ log _b a = \dfrac{log_u a} {log_u b} $ where $u$ is *any* real number. Read that backwards.

Comment: As a multiple choice Question, one way to add context is to identify one or more of the answers posed that you are able to eliminate.  Are there some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{Log_ca}{Log_cb}=Log_ba$$
$$\frac{Log_{11}5}{Log_{11}{15}}=Log_{15}{5}$$

Comment: Are u sure? I think answer is C.?

Comment: Which c? :)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              .........

Comment: are u sure that $Log_5 15$ is correct?

Comment: Yes! Also the answer must intuitively be less than one...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You have
$$
\log_{11}5=\frac{\log 5}{\log 11},\quad \log_{11}{15}=\frac{\log 15}{\log 11}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\log_{15} 5=\frac{\log_a 5}{\log_a 15}$$ where $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen the change of base formula for logarithms before: $\log_{a}{b}=\frac{\log_{x}{b}}{\log_{x}{a}}$? Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkFdDqW9xxM) to find out what it is and how to use it.

$$
\frac{\log_{11}{5}}{\log_{11}{15}}=\log_{15}{5}
$$

So, the answer is D.